# 3D orientations from distance constraints

Tags: algorithms, euclidean-geometry

I want to determine the relative orientations within a set of rigid 3D objects given some pairwise distances between certain points on pairs of objects. There are sufficient constrains to fully determine the orientations, but no pair of objects have a fixed relationship without considering distances to other objects. Is there a fast (preferably non-iterative) algorithm for this?